# can I use hide( "slow" ); with only the fadeout effect but without movement?

Tags: jquery, show-hide, fadeout

I have a div that I want to hide (the trigger is a mouseover).
But when I use

```
sym.$("theobjectIwanttohide").hide( "slow" );
```

the object not only *fades out*, it also *moves into a corner*.
I don't want that to happen,
does anyone know how this is done?

(I can not use .fadeout it has to be hidden)

edit:
and when I want to show a hidden div can I still use fadein for this?

Comment: Why are you not using `fadeOut`?

Comment: If fadeout doesn't hide it (which I think it actually does), use fadeout then hide it on completion http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think fadeOut hides on completion, but you could also use a callback:

```
$("theobjectIwanttohide").fadeout('slow', function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Update: "Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page."

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: OP : `(I can not use .fadeout it has to be hidden)`

Comment: Read the question. OP stated he cannot use `.fadeout()`.

Comment: @Adjit, not only is OP wrong, but the proposed solution calls `.hide()` on completion of fadeout.

Comment: @Smeegs fadeout does that anyway

Comment: @Popnoodles, I'm aware.  I'm just pointing out that the proposed solution is manually calling it.

Comment: @Smeegs thats what I thought, just wanted to make sure you guys knew what the OP said.

Answer (score 1):

*"I can not use .fadeout it has to be hidden"*

**Fadeout hides on completion.**

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

> The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements.
>   Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none,
>   so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

Look at the example and see that it hides after fading out.

http://jsfiddle.net/5jkuL/1/

```
sym.$("theobjectIwanttohide").fadeOut( "slow" );
```